# Docusaurus implementation in existing react project

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I am having one exiting react app and I want to embed Docusaurus into it to have documentation site.

Till now I have build the Docusuarus and put all the files/folder inside /build folder of Docusaurus app into my existing react application /public/my-docs folder.

When I run this in my local machine with npm run start command I am able to access my Docusaurus pages from http://localhost:3000/my-docs/intro

But when I build my existing react app by running "npm run build" and then I serve the build folder by using "npx serve -s build" command, my Docusuarus pages are not accessible from "http://localhost:3000/my-docs/intro".

I understand here I am trying to run two different react apps as single project, but I want to achieve below:

http://localhost:3000 -> My main react app should get served

http://localhost:3000/my-docs/intro -> My Docusaurus static pages should get loaded.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this case is covered in the [Docusaurus documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/docusaurus/docs/deployment.md)

> If you use routers that use the HTML5 pushState history API under the hood (for example, React Router with browserHistory), many static file servers will fail. For example, if you used React Router with a route for /todos/42, the development server will respond to localhost:3000/todos/42 properly, but an Express serving a production build as above will not.
>
> This is because when there is a fresh page load for a /todos/42, the
> server looks for the file build/todos/42 and does not find it. The
> server needs to be configured to respond to a request to /todos/42 by
> serving index.html. For example, we can amend our Express example
> above to serve index.html for any unknown paths:

Unfortunately, it seems that the answer is case-specific and depends on your individual set up and goals.